# Showing a message when a command crashes in powershell

Tags: powershell

When you start a command in a bash prompt on Linux, and that command crashes because it got a signal that was not handled, you get a helpful message from bash before returning to the prompt.

For example :

```
/home/user $ crash
Segmentation fault.
/home/user $
```

The default behavior in Powershell is to quietly return to the prompt with no indication that something went wrong.

Is there any way to get a similar behavior in Powershell ?

Note that a crashing program on windows will return a non-0 exit code, so displaying a message for all failure exit codes would also be a good solution.

However, it should work for all commands in the terminal as it is a "day-to-day usability" issue. I'm not interested in a way to enable this for a single program.

Comment: Powershell native comlets will have proper error routines with error messages. When it comes to running programs, it really is up to the program you run on how it handles errors. Some print the errors to stderr and others only set %errorlevel% upon exit.

Comment: To piggy-back on @LPChip's comment, for the latter, it will likely be recorded in Event Viewer [`eventvwr.msc`], and a function could be added to your PowerShell profile [`%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`] to output data from Event Viewer.

Comment: by default, PoSh tries to continue on with any given series of actions. to do that, it suppresses most non-fatal errors & just keeps on going. [*grin*] you can force it to stop with either the `$ErrorActionPreference` or with the common parameter that most cmdlets support - `-ErrorAction`. you can learn more about those with `Get-Help about_Preference_Variables` and `Get-Help about_CommonParameters`.